# How can I use a local folder as a dependency of another project in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a repository with the given structure: (All written in typescript)

```
.
├── common
├── project_1
└── project_2
```

I want common to be used by both project_1 and project_2 as a local dependency. How could this be done without using external tools like lerna etc? When I cd into project_1 and run `npm install`, I want project_1's dependencies installed and of course common package along with its own dependencies

Comment: Have you tried [`npm-link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link)? Or [`yarn link`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/)

Comment: Yes I've tried it. But it can't find the dependencies of the common package. "aws-cdk-lib" is added as a dependency to package.json of common. However when I try to run the project_1 it throws: Cannot find module 'aws-cdk-lib' or its corresponding type declarations.

EDIT: "aws-cdk-lib" is already installed in the node_modules of project_1. common exists in the node_modules of project_1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install), this is the way to do this:

```
npm install ../common
```

> npm install <folder>:
>
> If  sits inside  the root of your project, its dependencies will be installed and may be hoisted to the top-level node_modules as they would for other types of dependencies. If  sits outside the root of your project, npm will not install the package dependencies in the directory , but it will create a symlink to <folder>.

Comment: I tried it but again it throws the same error when I run cdk synth:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77023008/how-can-i-use-a-local-folder-as-a-dependency-of-another-project-in-typescript/77023098#comment135782184_77023008

Comment: You need to install `aws-cdk-lib` as a dependency in common as well, as it seems to depend on it. Just `cd common`, then `npm install aws-cdk-lib`. It doesn't matter if it is already installed in project_N, if common uses it, it must be installed as its dependency.